# Jupyter Notebookが起動しない（コマンドプロンプト：failed to create process.）

Tags: python, python3, windows, jupyter-notebook

#### 前提と問題

これまでJupyter Notebookを開く際、Windowsコマンドプロンプトで「Jupyter Notebook」と打つことで起動していたのですが、突然「failed to create process.」と言われ、起動しなくなりました。これを解決したいです。

考えられる原因としては、この直前にJupyter Notebookでプレゼンができるようになる拡張機能を導入する以下の操作を行っていました。

```
git clone https://github.com/damianavila/RISE
cd RISE
python setup.py install
```

最後の `python setup.py install` を実行することで、これまでJupyter Notebookを開けていた時の設定を何か変更してしまったのではないかと考えています。

初心者のためご教授いただければ幸いです。

同じ質問を以下のサイトでもしています。
https://teratail.com/questions/dzrg0y8lmwwj8l

#### 補足情報（FW/ツールのバージョンなど）

Windows10、Python 3.8.10、jupyter 1.0.0、notebook 6.4.8

Comment: 単なるユーザーとしての [Installation](https://rise.readthedocs.io/en/stable/installation.html) と、RISE自身を開発とかカスタマイズするための [Install RISE in developer mode](https://rise.readthedocs.io/en/stable/dev/develop.html#install-rise-in-developer-mode) とか新しい構成での開発らしい [Development](https://rise.readthedocs.io/en/stable/dev/develop.html) があるようで、その最後の手順に従っているようでいて実は微妙に違っている感じですが、やりたい事に合わせて正しく作業手順を完遂してみてはどうでしょう？

Comment: [他のサイトでも同じ内容の投稿](https://teratail.com/questions/dzrg0y8lmwwj8l) をされているようですが、予め質問の本文にその旨を明示しておいてもらうとスムーズに回答が付きやすくなると思います。 / 参考: [マルチポストとはなんですか？何か問題があるのでしょうか？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2418)

Comment: とりあえずpython 3.8.10 に jupyter 1.0.0 は入れずに ntebook 6.4.12 を入れた状態(他も最新)で git clone とかせず pip install RISE だけでインストールしたら、インストールの前も後も正常に起動出来ています。notebookファイル等をセーブした後で、いったん全部アンインストール/再インストールとか試してみてはどうでしょう？

Comment: ありがとうございます！　[jupyter 1.0.0をアンインストールし、再インストール](https://www.codetd.com/ja/article/13054295)した後、pip install RISE とすることで、問題が解決しました！ありがとうございました！！

Comment: 解決したなら、こちらでもコメントでは無く自己回答で閉めておきましょう。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[kunif](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/26370/kunif)さんのお力添えによって解決しました。
jupyter 1.0.0をアンインストールし、再インストールした後、pip install RISE とすることで、問題が解決しました。